# Picker not showing value in Xamarin.Forms on Windows Phone and UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use a `Picker` in an `ItemTemplate` and its Value is set via binding.

When my `ListView` is shown first time, it shows the value.

[image]

When I open its list, and set the value, the `Picker` remains empty.

[image]

[image]

If I open the list again, it shows the previously set value (also the binded object holds  the correct value).

[image]

This is the XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="picker"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="2"                                        
      SelectedIndex="{Binding MyValue}"
      TextColor="Black"
      VerticalOptions="Center"
      WidthRequest="70">
  <Picker.Items>
      <x:String>Start value</x:String>
      <x:String>1</x:String>
      <x:String>2</x:String>
```

What clears off the value?

**Bonus**: the text color is *white* in Windows Phone 8.1...agains the set `Black` color.

Here is the UI:

[image]

Here are the actual values in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a known bug in Xamarin.Forms according to [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41472).

"Fortunately", there is a workaround in the report that helps to make the `SelectedItem` appear.

You should create an invisible `Label` and bind its `Text` property to the `SelectedItem` of the `Picker`.

In XAML:

```
<Picker x:Name="pickerIn">
  <Picker.Items>
    <x:String>In - A</x:String>
    <x:String>In - B</x:String>
    <x:String>In - C</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
<Label IsVisible="False" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference pickerIn}, Path=SelectedIndex,StringFormat='The picker inside of TableView has index={0}'}" />
```