# Picker not showing value in ContentView in ViewCell

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

This question is very similar to [Picker not showing value in Xamarin.Forms on Windows Phone and UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388917/picker-not-showing-value-in-xamarin-forms-on-windows-phone-and-uwp) however there are some different aspects to this issue.  Also the workaround selected as an answer to that question does not work in this case.

I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate that contains a ContentView.  The ContentView contains a bindable picker.  When the picker is selected the selected value is not displayed.  This is an obvious bug because (1) you can resize the window and the value will appear and (2) this problem only occurs on UWP...iOS and Android versions are fine.

Here is the simplified issue. First the main window XAML...

```
    <StackLayout Padding="10,40">
        <Label>First List</Label>
        <ListView Margin="20"  x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemContexts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <local:ContentView1 
                                                 QuantityRows="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView1}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityRows}"
                                                 />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label>Second List</Label>
        <ListView Margin="20"  x:Name="listView2" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemContexts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Picker x:Name="quantity" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference listView2}, Path=BindingContext.QuantityView}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding FullName}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding QuantityRow, Converter={StaticResource QuantityValueConverter}}"
                            WidthRequest="200">
                            </Picker>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Label>End</Label>
    </StackLayout>
```

There are two list views.  The second one works fine and the first one illustrates the problem.

Here is the XAML for the content view...

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsBench.ContentView1" x:Name="contextView1">
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Picker x:Name="quantity" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference contextView1}, Path=QuantityRows}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding QuantityRow}"
                            WidthRequest="200">
        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Code behind for content view...

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ContentView1 : ContentView
{
    public static BindableProperty QuantityRowsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("QuantityRows", typeof(ObservableCollection<QuantityRow>), typeof(SummaryDetailView), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, null);
    public ObservableCollection<QuantityRow> QuantityRows
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(QuantityRowsProperty) as ObservableCollection<QuantityRow>;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(QuantityRowsProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public ContentView1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

}
}
```

Finally here is the view model...

```
public class QuantityRow
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        QuantityRows = new ObservableCollection<QuantityRow>();
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 1, Name = "Length" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 2, Name = "Diameter" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 3, Name = "Temperature" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 4, Name = "Pressure" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 5, Name = "Angle" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<QuantityRow> QuantityRows { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

I am using Xamarin Forms 2.3.4.247 which is the last stable release as of this writing.  I tried the latest pre-release which might fix the problem..it is impossible to say because it created a host of other issues.

I've tried invalidating the layout of the content view when the picker's selected index changes, but again, this seems to fix the one problem and create a host of other problems.

So it seems that this will be fixed in the next stable release of Xamarin Forms.  What I need now is an effective workaround so I can work with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and reproduced your issue. The problem is that your `BindingContext` of `ContentView1`  has never been set value. And this design is inconsequent, although it can work in the ios and andriod. For your requirement, you could realize it via custom `ViewCell`.

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinPickerTest.CustomViewCell">
  <ViewCell.View>
      <StackLayout>
            <Picker x:Name="quantity" ItemsSource="{Binding QuantityRows}" 
                           ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuantityRow}"
                            WidthRequest="200">
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
  </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        QuantityRows = new ObservableCollection<QuantityRow>();
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 1, Name = "Length" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 2, Name = "Diameter" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 3, Name = "Temperature" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 4, Name = "Pressure" });
        QuantityRows.Add(new QuantityRow() { ID = 5, Name = "Angle" });
    }
    private ObservableCollection<QuantityRow> quantityRows;
    public ObservableCollection<QuantityRow> QuantityRows
    {
        get
        {
            return quantityRows;
        }
        set
        {
            quantityRows = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private QuantityRow selectedQuantityRow;

    public QuantityRow SelectedQuantityRow
    {
        get { return selectedQuantityRow; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedQuantityRow != value)
            {
                selectedQuantityRow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class QuantityRow : ViewModelBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Usage**

```
<ListView Margin="20"  x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemContexts}" >
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <local:CustomViewCell/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

And the above solution works well in ios and android.

[image]

Comment: Well done!  I never considered writing a custom ViewCell. However I could not get it working exactly as you wrote it.  I had to add a bindable propery to the custom view cell to get the picker list.  Also I would not characterize this as a solution, but a workaround.  But exactly what I ask for.